# Column duplicating on resize Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a Card that has a image and some text inside it and that it doesn't overflows depending on the window size since it's not that much info. It doesn't matter if the text isn't shown nicely.
But I have bumped into this problem that overflows when the size of the screen is really small and [it duplicates the column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajpBp.gif)

Here is the code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar( title: Text(widget.title)),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(children: [
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 5,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => card()
          )
        ])
      )
    );
  }

  card() {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 10, 5, 0),
        child: Card(
          elevation: 5,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder( borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),),
          child: Material(
            color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
            child: Ink( child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: FittedBox(child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top: 10),
                child: productInfo()
              ))
            ))
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }

  productInfo(){
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        FittedBox(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints( maxWidth: 130.0, maxHeight: 130),
              child: Text('image', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10))
            )
          )
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [ info("name"), info("value") ]
          )
        ),
      ]
    );
  }

  info(String text){
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 168,
        child: Text( text, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, softWrap: false, maxLines: 2, textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the size of the screen is really small, you have to consider that you used `padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 10, 5, 0),` inside your `Container()`. It works as expected.